# "Enum annotation value must be an enum constant" when enabling kapt for RequestMethod.POST

Tags: spring, kotlin, enums, kapt

I have an interesting error, with the following kotlin code:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v2/job/raywhite-sync/listings")
class RayWhiteSyncListingsController() {
    
    @RequestMapping(
        value = ["/all/{org}"],
        method = [RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET],
    )
    fun syncAllListingsInit(@PathVariable("org") org : String): Ok {
    
        return Ok.ok()
    }
        
}
```

Upon enabling kapt (by adding any `kapt` depedency to my `depedencies {}`, doesn't matter what the processor is, I've tried different ones just in-case) I get the following error:

```java
/upside-core/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/main/upside/controllers/jobs/raywhite/RayWhiteSyncListingsController.java:43: error: an enum annotation value must be an enum constant
    @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping(value = {"/all/{org}"}, method = {org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST, org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET})
```

However `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST` *is* an Enum constant.

I've tried removing other plugins, etc. I am using spring-boot 2.7.11 (including the spring boot dependency plugin, Kotlin 1.8.21 (also tried 1.9.0-RC), and java 17.

I'm running out of ideas to try to debug this so if anyone has a similar error then that would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error you provided reads: `value = {"/all/{org}"}`. Where is this path in the code? I think you're showing the wrong `RequestMapping` in your example.

Comment: Ah, sorry my bad - copied the wrong method when making a minimal example, will update